# Difference between Ragged Right and Fixed Length

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Can any one explain me what is the difference between Ragged Right and Fixed Length in flat file connection manager,with an Example

When to use Ragged Right and  Fixed Length

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms139941.aspx) covers this pretty well.

Fixed length records have fixed length values for all fields.  For instance, the following has three fields that are each 10 characters, starting at positions 1, 10, and 20:

```
Name     $200.10   Comment    <\n>
Name2    $200.10   Comment2   <\n>
---------1---------2---------3
```

The <\n> represents the end of the line.

A ragged format allows the last line to be variable length:

```
Name     $200.10   Comment<\n>
Name2    $200.10   Comment2<\n>
---------1---------2---------3
```

It is a way of having a variable length field in otherwise fixed length data.  This would typically be used for comments and is a way to save space.